# How can I create a customized colormap for geoviews (bokeh)?

Tags: bokeh, python-xarray, holoviews, geoviews

I'm trying to plot an xarray dataset in Geoviews, like this:

https://geoviews.org/gallery/bokeh/xarray_image.html#bokeh-gallery-xarray-image

There I can define a colormap by cmap.

The cmap is just a list of hex-codes, like:

['#150b00',
'#9b4e00',
'#f07800',
'#ffa448',
'#a8a800',
'#dddd00',
'#ffff00',
'#ffffb3',
'#ffffff',
'#b0ffff',
'#00e8e8',
'#00bfbf',
'#008a8a',
'#79bcff',
'#0683ff',
'#0000c1',
'#000048']

I want to define to levels of values for these color, like this list:

[-10.0,
-5.0,
-2.5,
-1.0,
-0.5,
-0.2,
-0.1,
-0.05,
0.05,
0.1,
0.2,
0.5,
1.0,
2.5,
5.0,
10.0]

How can I define these levels?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set the parameter `color_levels` to the wanted values. This is explained in [HoloViews Styling Plots](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Styling_Plots.html) in the section **Custom color intervals**. HoloVies is the source where the `gv.Image` comes from. Therefore this should work.

```
cmap = ['#150b00', '#9b4e00', '#f07800', '#ffa448', '#a8a800', '#dddd00', '#ffff00', '#ffffb3', '#ffffff', '#b0ffff', '#00e8e8', '#00bfbf', '#008a8a', '#79bcff', '#0683ff', '#0000c1', '#000048']
levels = [-10.0, -5.0, -2.5, -1.0, -0.5, -0.2, -0.1, -0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.5, 5.0, 10.0]

images.opts(
    cmap=cmap,
    color_levels=levels,
    colorbar=True,
    width=600, 
    height=500) * gf.coastline
```

**Comment**

If this is not working, then I apologize. In the moment I am not able to install `GeoViews` on my machine.